# With Babel why does a functions length property change depending on async or not?

Tags: javascript, babeljs

Given the following I'd expect the same result from both `length`s:

```
const foo = (...args) => { }
console.log(foo.length)  // 0
const asyncFoo = async (...args) => { }
console.log(asyncFoo.length)  // 1
```

But the `async` modifier makes a difference. Is this as per the ES7 spec that `async` changes the length parameter?

Note: this isn't just esoteric. I was tripped up because Mocha behaves differently depending on the test function's `length`. I couldn't figure out why everything stopped working when I changed a test wrapper function to `async`.

Comment: No, this does not conform to the standard. You'll want to file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi. I thought I'd post here first as I wasn't sure if it was incorrect behaviour.

Comment: [Issue posted](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4891)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at how Babel transpiles `async` functions, this result will make more sense. You can see [a simple example here](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=latest%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=let%20a%20%3D%20(...args)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log('Hello%20World!')%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20f%20%3D%20async%20(...args)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log('Hello%20World!')%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(a.length)%3B%0Aconsole.log(f.length)%3B&playground=true).

You can see that the original transpiled function has no parameters to the method (hence the `length` of 0).

The transpiled method, on the other hand, ends up being (even though it doesn't actually need to be):

```
function f(_x) {
  return _ref.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Since the generated function has a single argument, the `length` is 1.

This behavior does not seem to be part of the `async`/`await` spec (which can be found at https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/#async-function-instances-length)

Comment: This really looks like a bug, though. There's no reason for that `_x` to be there.

Comment: That does look like the technical reason but my question is is that as per the ES7 spec? I was going to file a Github issue in Babel but it suggested SO, and since I wasn't sure if this is incorrect behaviour I posted here first.

Comment: @DamonMaria - No. I've updated the answer with a link to the relevant bit of the specification. The behavior of `length` should mimic that of a regular function and only show the expected number of arguments.